# firefox is pushing div to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

This is my first question and I am a supper noobie, but am eager to learn.

I have this site http://autogoog.com/site/#about that is written & styled in html/css.

The site looks great on chrome and safari, but on firefox, the Team page is being pushed out to the right.

Here is the html portion and below is the css.  Any help would be amazing and thankful.

```
<!-- TEAM STARTS
     ========================================================================= -->
  <section id="team">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 section-heading animated" style="text-align:center" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0">
              <h2>Leadership</h2>
              <h1>meet the team</h1>
              <p class="line">&nbsp;</p>
           </div>           
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="our-team">
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:jay@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">JAY LEOPARDI</div>
              <div class="designation">FOUNDER & CEO</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jay.leopardi.1?fref=ts"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Jay Leopardi, lifestyle and pop culture branding expert, is the founder & CEO of Bad Boy Branding.  Working with start-ups to top tier brands, he reinvents the traditional structure of brand development. Visit <a href="http://www.JayLeopardi.com/" target="_blank">JAYLEOPARDI.COM</a> to find out more detailed information.</div>
        </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:shawn@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">SHAWN C. LEOPARDI</div>
              <div class="designation">COO</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/shawn.leopardi"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Expert in marketing & business operations, Shawn brings over 20 years of expertise to Bad Boy Branding. His processes have been proven to build mega-corporations from $20-80 million in annual revenue.</div>                  
           </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:anthony@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">ANTHONY MARABELLA</div>
              <div class="designation">VP SALES & MARKETING</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/anthony.marabella"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Anthony leads a team of highly skilled business professionals while maintaining a great balance of customer care and dynamic sales techniques. He has implemented custom-tailored digital strategies that power the bullets at Bad Boy Branding.</div>                  
           </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:danielle@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">DANIELLE BYNUM</div>
              <div class="designation">VP BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Known in the industry as “The Business Development Shark”, Bad Boy Branding depends on Danielle’s efficient and highly seasoned business senses. Having worked directly for “The Shark” Daymond John, she has learned how to develop relationships worldwide with major corporations.  Additionally, Danielle empowers BBB with an evolutionary, hyper-speed licensing model.</div>                  
           </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:barry@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">BARRY SHRUM,ESQ.</div>
              <div class="designation">CORPORATE LEGAL</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Barry Neil Shrum, Esquire, aka “The Bad Boy of Legal”, has been practicing entertainment & corporate law for over 16 years.  Having represented some of the biggest names in the industry, Barry safeguards BBB and the interests of its clients. As a result of doing business with Jay Leopardi for over a decade, they formed an acquisitions corporation to purchase brands that align well with BBB’s business model.</div>                  
           </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:hutson@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">HUTSON MILLER</div>
              <div class="designation">VP ENTERTAINMENT</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hutson.miller"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Former Atlantic Records/WEA executive & broker of the LA Lakers Owner Dr. Jerry Buss, Hutson works directly with top musicians, producers, professional athletes and celebrity entertainers. His list includes Brandy, Lil Kim, Pharrell Williams, Wyclef Jean, Jason Kidd, Desean Jackson, Tom Cruise & the list goes on. Working with Jay Leopardi for the past decade, developing a solid personal & business relationship, he now leads the entertainment division of Bad Boy Branding.</div>
           </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:pablo@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">PABLO FONSECA</div>
              <div class="designation">CREATIVE DIRECTOR</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pfon72"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Expert TV broadcasting & creative director, Pablo has worked for major corporations such as Univision, Telemundo, and the Zimmerman agency. Leading BBB’s creative team & managing a host of dynamic designers, he creates award-winning content that brings significant value. High profile clients, such as Ashley furniture, Nissan national, and Atlantis, have all received Pablo’s creative stamp.</div>
           </div>
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="0">
              <div class="picture"><a href="mailto:michael@badboybranding.com?subject=BAD BOY BRANDING INQUIRY" class="teamoverlayzoom"><img src="img/team/7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""><span class="zoom"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></span></a></div>
              <div class="heading">MICHAEL SIEGLE</div>
              <div class="designation">IA DIRECTOR</div><br>
              <div class="team-social"><a href="https://twitter.com/JewHefner"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MichaelSiegle"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/101927035231881379587/posts"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></div>
              <p class="smallline">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="description">Well traveled & world-renowned information architect, Michael is a strategic and high level thinker autonomously managing BBB’s technical development teams.</div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
  <!-- /.TEAM -->
```

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Team Section Starts */

```
#team {
    background: url(../img/textures/zwartevilt.png);
}
#team .line {
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #373737;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#team .team-contents {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#team .picture {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
#team .picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}
#team .heading {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#team .designation {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 3px;
}
#team .smallline {
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #373737;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.team-contents .icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    top: -60px;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
#team .description {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    color: gray;
}
#team .team-social a {

    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    color: #d0d0d0;
}
#team .team-social a i {
}
/* Team Overlayzoom Starts */
.teamoverlayzoom {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.teamoverlayzoom span i {
    color: #000;
}
.teamoverlayzoom span.zoom {
    position: absolute;
    nowhitespace: afterproperty;
    nowhitespace: afterproperty;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(256, 256, 256); /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.teamoverlayzoom span.zoom span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.teamoverlayzoom:hover span.zoom, .teamoverlayzoom:focus span.zoom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(256, 256, 256); /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle and/or possibly specify the piece of code that breaks your theme.

Comment: Yes, like @unableToCompile stated, please provide us with a jsFiddle so we can see your code in action, along with testing some solutions on it.

Comment: I have placed your code into a jsFiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/axUHA/, although I cannot see any difference between Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera...

Comment: Try it again(not on jsFiddle). Resize your browser, you may be dealing with size issues.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct as this is my 1st jsfiddle attempt.  If there is something missing, please lmk.http://jsfiddle.net/t6hAV/

Comment: I tried resizing the browser.  I am using a 27' screen and it's still pushed all the way over to the right.

Comment: So, what is being pushed to the right? I don't know If I am looking at the same thing as you. Is it the text?

Comment: Check http://autogoog.com/site/#about  click team.  Check it on chrome or safari and then firefox.

Comment: this sort of example won't work for JSfiddle. Can you specify the block of code in question?

Comment: Pardon any of my ignorance.  But if you would 
 
Check autogoog.com/site/#about click team. Check it on chrome or safari and then firefox.  You will see what I am talking about.

Comment: @fizzix I am not understanding this either.  Would you please check autogoog.com/site/#about then click team. Check it on chrome or safari and then firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  There was an error in the section of #team. Was missing some necessary divs. It is all fixed now.  Thank you all for your help.

```
  <section id="team">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 section-heading animated" style="text-align:center" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0">
              <h2>OUR TEAM</h2>
              <h1>meet the team</h1>
              <p class="line">&nbsp;</p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="our-team">
           <div class="team-contents animated" data-animation="flipInX" data-animation-delay="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have much time but I will let you work about with a css browser specific css "hack". I am posting this just in case you find it useful :

So, this isn't the best solution but it should work.

```
/* IE7, FF */
html>body #team.container { 
    position: relative;
    right: 700px;
}
```

This simply targets those specific browsers. This is not a "good" solution because browser specific css is bad practice. I might look at this tomorrow. Good luck.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will give it a shot to see if this works.  I will check in tomorrow to see if you would guide me into learning the proper fix.  Thank you again unableToCompile

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot even get the hack you posted to work.